# What color wallpaper makes page control dots on iPhone invisible?

Tags: iphone, screen, color

What color wallpaper do I need to use to make the page control dots invisible?

I know, you can't really hide them, as in **remove from the screen** (without iOS jailbreaking) but you can make them almost invisible if you select the right color of the wallpaper.

I have tried using two different wallpapers, while one makes them almost invisible the other does not, but the dots are over the same color on both wallpapers.

[image] [image]

Answer (score 2):

You **can't** make the dots completely invisible.

The [iOS SpringBoard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpringBoard) (or Home screen as it is generally called) is programmed such that the [Page Controls](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/controls/page-controls/) (dots) which appear just above the Dock remain legible irrespective of the colour of the wallpaper in the background. This is done by assigning them colors which are in **contrast** to the colour of the background.

The logic ensures that **at-least** the colour of the dot representing the current page of Home screen is most clearly visible.

There is no publicly available official document to back this fact. The conclusion can be reached by performing a small experiment as described:

1. Set the background to solid `#000000` or `RGB: 0, 0, 0` (Black color).

[image]

2. Get the color code for the Page Control dots corresponding to **non-current** screens. Notice the colour code for the dots. The value is `#727374` or `RGB: 114, 115, 116`.

[image]

3. Create a solid colored background image of resolution equal to that of iPhone's screen (*640 x 1136* in my case, iPhone 5s), with the above noted color code and assign it as iPhone background. The color code was picked corresponding to **non-current** screen dots as they can have more than one instances.

[image]

4. Now once again, get the color code for the Page Control dots corresponding to non-current screens. It can be observed that the colour for the dots has changed.

[image]

5. Now, create a solid colored background image with colour code `#FFFFFF` or `RGB: 255, 255, 255` (White colour). Once again, notice the color of the dots. The color corresponding to the current screen has changed from **White** in first image to **Black** in the current image.

[image]

---

**P.S.**: I have played around a lot with both macOS and iOS to minimise eye-candy by working through such tricks. Above conclusion is just an observation without any documented backing from Apple. The attached iPhone home screen screenshots have been scaled down to **50%** of their original resolution.

Comment: Although, I must admit, using White colour as the background makes for some fancy looking icons (the ones with white background), looking like their Android counterpart.

Comment: But as you can see on the left hand image in my OP, the dots are almost completely hidden. But for some reason the dots turned white on the right hand image, although they are over exactly the same background color, just the image itself contains more darker colours. So maybe there has to be some specific combination of colours? So basically I want to change the white color from the left hand image for darker grey color form the right hand image. But when I do so, the dots turn white.

Comment: You are right. As I understand, with some experimenting it is possible to minimise the colour contrast, but it's not possible to **completely** make the dots invisible.